# Bootstrap Vertically div full background

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, vertical-alignment

I'm using bootstrap framework for a project, but I'm having trouble with a central div for my site.

I need to put a div vertically centered but with a background color for 100% full width, and inside  the container div of bootstrap.

I need to build the blue part (Central DIV) of the image http://www.hmsg.net/layout.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<div class="col-lg-12"
     style="padding:0px; background-image: url('http://www.kiteworldmag.com/media/wallpapers/2/187/3.jpg'); background-size: 100% auto; height:500px;;">
  <div class="col-lg-12" style="height:300px; padding:0px; margin:0px; display: block">
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-12" style="background-color:#ffffff; height:100px; padding:0px; margin:0px;">
    sdfsdf
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

use this

```
     <div class="col-lg-12" style="background: url("../img/Bg.png"); background-size: 100% auto; height:100%;">
 <div class="col-lg-12" style="hieght:500px; padding:0px; margin:0px;">
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-12" style="background-color:#ffffff; hieght:500px; padding:0px; margin:0px;">
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Hi Harutyun,  
I think your example don't work for me.
I want to do something like this http://www.hmsg.net/layout_example.jpg . My problem is the middle div that i can't put it center vertically and have a 100% width background.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Harutyun, for your answer,

I've ended with this solution:

```
<div style="margin:0; padding:0px; width:100%; height:100%; display:table">
     <div style="display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle;" >
          <div style="background:#99FF33">
               <div class="container">Content Goes Here.</div>
          </div>
     </div>
</div>
```